# How to deploy two .jar files on the same port?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jenkins

I want to know how to deploy two different .jar files on the same port using Jenkins.

The two .jar files is build by Jenkins, i just want to know if there are any better options than re-doing the projects to build .war files and deploy them using a single Tomcat container?

edit:
The reason i'm asking the questions is because i'm building a webapp using multiple microservices, therefor i'm interested in how to do this with "best practice".

Comment: It's impossible to run multiple applications on the same port, and it's also impossible to run multiple JAR files on the same JVM, so it's probably not possible. However, you can always add a reverse proxy so that they're both running "on the same port" (= the port of the reverse proxy), but I don't know if that solves your question. Maybe it could be helpful to add into the question why you want to make them run on the same port.

Comment: The best practice would be to either merge them into a single application, or deploy them as wars in tomcat. Or use something like a OSGI based platform that allows you to hot-deploy modules (which is essentially the same as deploying wars in tomcat...)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a common point of access that your clients can use to access your services. You can achieve this by creating an API gateway service that routes requests to the correct service. Your original two services listen on different ports, but your client only has to know about the API gateway endpoints, the API gateway itself will route the requests.

Have a look at [Spring-cloud-zuul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html) or this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/) to see how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, that sounds like a very good solution.